# How to fetch all resources from Firebase database with nested security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

In firebase, is it possible to configure a rule so that when a parent resource is fetched, it only returns child items that the user as access to?

I have a data structure like so:

```js
{
  application_access_request: {
    app_id_1: {
      access_key_1: {
        email: "abc@b.com"
      },
    },
    app_id_2: {
      access_key_2: {
        email: xyz@c.com
      },
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have rules like so:

```js
{
  "application_access_request": {
      "$appId": {
        "$accessId": {
          ".read": "data.child($accessId).child('email').val() === auth.token.email",
        },
      }
    },
}
```

As a user logged in with email `abc@b.com`,
When I request all resources from `application_access_request/`,
Then I want `app_id_1` and it's children to be accessable / returned to the user,

Is it possible to allow reading of all `application_access_request` but only return apps that the auth'd user has access to?

Answer (score 1):

No, security rules cannot be used to selectively return information (see [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters)). You may, however, be able to use querying to solve this use case. For example, if your data was structured:

```js
{
  application_access_request: {
    app1: {
      access_key: "user@example.com"
    },
    app2: {
      access_key: "user2@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

You can use [query-based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) to limit querying:

```js
"application_access_request": {
  ".read": "auth.uid != null && auth.token.email_verified &&
            query.orderByChild == 'access_key' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.token.email"
}
```

Comment: Query filters could work nice. What is the `access_key` in your example though? In my example it is a randomly generated string and the user querying won't know its value. Is it always the same string in your example?

Comment: Yes, if you want to be able to query across many nodes you'll need to have a stable key to query against (this could be in addition to the randomly generated access keys).